# Wikipedia API requests for english page and spanish equivalent. Unable to retrieve spanish JSON for recentchanges

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'm attempting to use the wikipedia API. However, I'm finding that I can only retrieve recent changes for english pages. For example:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges&rctitle=Battle%20of%20Palma&format=json`

returns:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "recentchanges": [{
            "type": "edit",
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Battle of Palma",
            "pageid": 67226819,
            "revid": 1061578435,
            "old_revid": 1049512969,
            "rcid": 1455128770,
            "timestamp": "2021-12-22T15:19:02Z"
        }]
    }
}
```

However, the same request with the same page in Spanish returns an empty array:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges&rctitle=Batalla%20de%20Palma&format=json`

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"recentchanges":[]}}
```

Even though both of the pages exist:

- English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Palma
- Spanish: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalla_de_Palma

Comment: Look at the URLs for the pages... notice anything? you need to use es.wikipedia if you want the Spanish article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the incorrect API call. The above provides any changes across wikipedia. I needed to use the history call found here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:REST_API/Reference#Get_page_history